# Why im getting id number on discord.js with message.mentions.members.first()

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I was updating my bot to discord.js 13V on the update when I mention somone I trhows me [image]

this is the code im husing `

```
const   galletita1=  new Discord.MessageEmbed()

        .setDescription(message.author.username + `  Toma una galletita `    +  message.mentions.members.first())
       .setFooter({
text:"espero te guste"})
        .setColor(' #FFFF00')
        .setImage('http://pm1.narvii.com/6559/7ce32024e00c60cb695a8e838d5bcaf3264bc612_hq.jpg')
```

`

in the past version this work to display the username of the member you mention but now i get the number id

i tried to declare a variable with the message.mentions.members.first() and it works the same

Answer (score 0):

`message.mentions.members` I believe is a collection of guild members, so `message.mentions.members.first()` will return a guild member.

To get the user, I think you want `message.mentions.members.first().user`

Answer (score 0):

the answer is to delcare the variable

```
 const Target = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
```

and "text" + Target.username